# MySQL 'load data infile' loading exactly half the records

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8

I have a weird problem.
I'm trying to load a csv file with 59153 rows into mysql table with this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/x.csv'
INTO TABLE Addresses
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

It does work, but exactly half of the data gets written in the database.

If I use
`LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`
as several answers suggested, nothing gets written in the database and no error message:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

There must be something with the .csv file because I checked everything else in the code and it's correct.

I would like to avoid editing the .csv file because it's coming from an external source.

Any pointers?

Comment: Is it loading every other line, or the first half of the file?

Comment: seems to be random:| 58360 |
| 58361 | 
| 58362 |  
| 58365 | 
| 58366 |  
| 58368 |  
| 58370 |

Comment: Look at the file with a hex dump and see if you can see a difference between the way those lines are encoded versus the missing lines.

Comment: *seems to be random* @Barmar asks not about `id` values in destination table but about loaded rows physical posession in source CSV. PS. If loading fails on some row then all previous rows (rows which were loaded before failed one) are not removed (LOAD DATA is non-transactional statement).

Comment: @Akina I assumed the IDs in the CSV files are sequential, so the gaps there show lines that weren't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I opened the .csv file with Numbers on a mac and exported to CSV Unicode (UTF-8) and now it's loading properly. Something was off with the formatting. Thank you everyone for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Doesn't a Mac have just `\r` as the line terminator?